# Call WCF Service from Windows service via DLL

Tags: c#, wcf, dll

Basically my situation is this:

```
Windows Service --Calls--> MethodinDLL --Calls--> WCFService.
```

Service configuration is written on the DLL side manually, and on windows service side in config - I am insterested if WCF parameters on DLL side and on the Windows service side should match. More elaboration below.

I will tell you my setup. I call WCF Service from DLL. There is code **inside DLL** which calls WCF service such as this:

```
//Inside DLL
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:16593/FreeSpaceDatabase.svc");

YourServiceClient proxy = new YourServiceClient(binding, epa);
```

I manually provide parameters as you can see.

Now, I have a windows service which actually refers to this DLL, and using DLL (or via DLL), calls the WCF Service. (The call to WCF Service is located in DLL - windows service doesn't have method to call WCF Service).

But I was forced to still add this on **the Windows service side:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFreeSpaceDatabase" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:16593/FreeSpaceDatabase.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFreeSpaceDatabase"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IFreeSpaceDatabase" name="BasicHttpBinding_IFreeSpaceDatabase" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My question is what if the `EndpointAddress("http://localhost:16593/FreeSpaceDatabase.svc")` which I specify in the code **on the DLL side**(like in the beginning of my question):

```
  EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:16593/FreeSpaceDatabase.svc");
```

is different from the endpoint address specified in the `AppConfig` file as of the **Windows service**? Is it allowed? Or they should always be the same?

Comment: if you specify the url within the code, i think this will take precedence over what is in AppConfig

Comment: @user1230756: Yeah but like I said before I had referenced WCF in the DLL from using "Add Service reference .. " etc. But I still had to add WCF service reference on the Windows service side (I was getting error). Now I changed in DLL so that I specify endpoint in code .. My question is what to do on Windows service side? Should the parameters match in code on DLL side and in config on Windows service?

Comment: I guess since you are doing the "Add service Reference" option its adding the entries in the config. You would not need the entries in the config. You might still need reference to System.ServiceModel.dll on the windows service as its the entry point. Also its a good practice not to hard code values in code rather drive them from configs.

Comment: @Rajesh: how to reference Servicemodel.dll? Ps. Like I said I am interested basically should endpoint address on dll side in code, match endpoint address in config of windows service?

Comment: Just "Add Reference" on the windows service project should help you to add a reference to System.ServiceModel.dll.

Comment: @Rajesh: Is it neccessary? btw I have deleted whole config from DLL side and it still seems to work(because on DLL side remember I had it in code). But on Windows service I didn't remove anything yet

Comment: You can remove the config entries from the windows service config file as well as your code has all values and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this address from your config and it should work. I have these settings (bindings and endpoints) in my code and only this in my config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings />
    <client />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: You also call wcf via dll?

Comment: I have my service in a dll and reference it from another project (windows service project). Client is an mvc application. I suppose there is no difference where these settings should be located. They should be either in your main app code (the one that uses dll) or in the code itself (the one that consumes wcf service)